# Remove from Viewport not in Unreal anymore?

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I have a menu / UI widget in Unreal Engine v4.9.2 and I realised that "Remove from Viewport" isn't available anymore? Is there any alternative? I just need the menu to close after clicking the button on the screen.

Here's my current blueprint:
[image: blueprint]

Any help is great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Unreal Engine 4.6, you now use `RemoveFromParent` which removes the widget from whatever its parent is (e.g. the viewport). This is exposed to blueprint.

[The release notes mention in the C++ API changes the following](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?53230-Unreal-Engine-4-6-Released):

> RemoveFromViewport is now deprecated, use RemoveFromParent.